# Is there any method in selenium which will return absolute xpath by passing relative xpath to the method

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, xpath-2.0

I have some situations in which i can identify the element by using relative xpath and in return i need to get the absolute xpath (from root) of the element. So I want to know if there is any method in selenium like that. You can also suggest me if any alternative you know for this.

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think ByChanged can help with that.

```
By locatorBase = By.xpath("./div/div[contains(@class,'listRoot')]";
By relativeLocator = getNthZElementLocator("2");
ByChanged chainedLocator = new ByChained(locatorBase, relativeLocator);
```

And, you can do variations on what I show above to accomplish whatever you need.

```
String XPATH_Z_ELEMENT_STRING = ".//ul/li[%s]";
public By getNthZElementLocator(String replaceArg)
{
    return By.xpath(String.format(XPATH_Z_ELEMENT_STRING, replaceArg));
}
```